# pubnub subscribe `withPresence` returns 403

Tags: pubnub

Even though `read` permission for the channel `ch.123.456` is enabled:

```
{resources: {channels: {ch.123.456: { read: true... }}}
```

pubnub, when I try to subscribe to the channel with

```
pubnub.subsribe({channels: ['ch.123.456'], withPresence: true})
```

returns

```
{"message":"Forbidden","payload":{"channels":["ch.123.456-pnpres"],"channel-groups":[],"users":[],"spaces":[],"uuids":[]},"error":true,"service":"Access Manager","status":403}
```

Pubnub sdk version 5.0.0.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

Try granting access to the Presence channel ch.123.456-pnpres
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/security/access-control#publishsubscribe

Comment: Thanks, this got the thing working. What kept confusing me, is the documentation here https://www.pubnub.com/docs/presence/presence-events#subscribing-to-presence-channel says `When you enable the withPresence flag, the SDK automatically subscribes you to presence channels.`, so I thought that I don't have to do this `-pnpres` append manually but the SDK is going to this for me since I do want to subscribe to the presence events on all of the subscribed channels